# vb.net position cursor one space greater than text box length

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a TextBox and it contains this text "File Was Created"
I would like to place the cursor one space over from the end of this text in the TextBox
I am trying to NOT say Simple Enough Task BUT I have wasted 2 hours with no solution
YES I know if I change the text to this "File Was Created " it will work NOT a solution

Here is the code mess I have tried

```
        Dim L As Integer
        L = tbMessage.Text.Length
        L += 1
        'tbMessage.Text = CStr(L)
        'tbHaveTwo.Text = frmOne.vR
        'Me.ActiveControl = tbMessage
        'tbMessage.SelectionStart = tbMessage.Text.Length

        tbMessage.SelectionStart = L
        tbMessage.Select()<br/>
```

Here is Two updated ways to solve this issue Jimi way less code

```
         tbMessage.Text = "File Was Created"
        'This Code involves more code 
        'Dim str As String
        'str = Mid(tbMessage.Text, tbMessage.Text.Length)
        'If str <> " " Then
        '    tbMessage.Text = tbMessage.Text & " "
        'End If
        'Answer from Jimi Works Great 
        tbMessage.AppendText(ChrW(32))
        tbMessage.SelectionStart = tbMessage.Text.Length
        tbMessage.Select()
```

Comment: Do you mean `tbMessage.SelectionStart = tbMessage.TextLength`? Do you have just that text in your TextBox? Or do you need to find it? What does *one space over* implies? Do you want to insert a space after that string, in case it's the only one there?

Comment: @Jimi All that is in the TextBox is "File Was Created"  NO I can see it I want to place the cursor one space to the RIGHT of the text When the TextBox gains Focus Do NOT want to insert a space after the string UNLESS that is the only option I can not understand why L += 1 does not work

Comment: If you have just that text and you want the caret to move **ONE SPACE** after the Text, you have to add a space at the end of that Text, otherwise there's nothing to move the caret to. You can set `SelectionStart = 100000000`, it will be always positioned at the end of that, lonely, string, not some thousands of (non-existing) spaces after.

Comment: Unless you just want to draw a caret one space after your string. We could come up with a solution using Graphics. That would be fun

Comment: @djv Not sue using Graphics would be fun but it would be a lot of work and overkill

Comment: You just need `tbMessage.AppendText(ChrW(32)) tbMessage.SelectionStart = tbMessage.TextLength`

Comment: @Jimi It wants an End Of Statement and the 2nd tbMessage is RED I did add the period before the word Length ? ? ?

Comment: `TextLength` is a property, no period required. You didn't send to a new line `tbMessage.SelectionStart = tbMessage.TextLength`. Of course, those I posted before are **two** (2) lines of code!

Comment: Just having some fun

Comment: @Jimi Great Answer I Posted some updated CODE in the Question to reflect your solution which is the simplest way to solve the question I also posted a solution that requires too much code FWIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't end up with a ton of spaces on the end of your message?

```
tbMessage.AppendText(If(tbMessage.Text.EndsWith(" "), "", " "))
tbMessage.SelectionStart = tbMessage.TextLength
tbMessage.Focus()
```

Comment: this is the most frustrating simple task Now when I navigate back to the form that has tbMessage I can not give it Focus Tab Index is 0 Not a NEW Question Just way too much work to control Navigation

Comment: In order to regain focus on the start up Form that is not closed but Me.Hide just before you navigate to the new Form make this call Me.Dispose() then Me.Hide and frmTwo.Show ON the trip back from frmTwo the TextBox will gain focus

Comment: In the context of this question, your extra comments mean very little.  If you need help with focus issues, I'd open a new question and post the code that is opening and closing the forms in question.  Something isn't right there...

Comment: I agree with you my comment above your comment explains what I did I might add that I did something different with Hiding and showing all other forms than the StartUp form I wrote a function in a Module All I know is you can not use Me.Close on the StartUp form in properties I have all forms set to When the Last form Close